# what callback with a view object is called with method fullCaledar('refetchEvents')?

Tags: fullcalendar

When I refetch / update my calendar with events, I need to update another panel outside the calendar to reflect the new changes. The problem is, when I call

$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')

no relevant callback is called with access to a view object. I need the view object so I can get the start and end dates for the calendar view.

The 'viewDisplay' callback is not called.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you would need this feature:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=753
(not yet implemented).

once you know all the events have been rendered, you could call `getView` to get the start/end range. (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/getView/)